# Changing the TERM variable value

Tags: linux

What really is the `TERM` variable set in `/etc/inittab` entries? How does it influence the system behavior? Can You provide some examples changing the vale of it?

Answer (score 0):

The `TERM` variable is inherited by all processes that `init` launches. It ensures that all processes that are spawned by `init` use the proper terminal formatting for output to the console.

For example, if you were to set the `TERM` to `rxvt` you might get strange results with applications trying to output colored messages or other control characters.

<sub>It seems it's much harder to find examples for this than I anticipated; especially since most modern terminal emulators are really good at hiding these kinds of problems.</sub> It seems like Gnome terminal (`xterm`) and `regent25` terminal type together mess up the backspace key:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: To test it i've changed the `Terminal-type string` value from default xterm to rxvt in the Putty SSH client but nothing seems to change - i can still successfully login & type commends on the remote Linux system.

Comment: I added an example of where terminal type inconsistencies lead to problems.

Comment: Thx for answer and example. In case of ssh setting it's vale in the ssh client (Putty for e.g. in Terminal-type field) causes the client itself to choose  the proper output formatting or is it (also) sended to to the server and if so what has it to do with it?

Comment: It does send it to the server, and the server will send the appropriate control messages back to the terminal (PuTTY in this case, although SSH has nothing to do with it, it's just a transport mechanism). However, PuTTY is quite good at emulating several terminal types, so finding an error there won't be easy.